# Javadoc: Treat warnings as errors?

Tags: ant, javadoc

Is it possible to treat warnings as errors when using Javadoc? In particular, I am calling Javadoc from Ant and have `failonerror="true"` set on my `<javadoc>` task, but I cannot seem to trigger this. Even though `javadoc` is generating warnings, I am still getting `BUILD SUCCESSFUL` with an exit code of `0` when Ant completes.

I would expect to be able to add something to the `additionalparam` attribute of the `<javadoc>` task to force a failure for Javadoc warnings.

Comment: There is a difference between `failonerror` and `failonwarnings` (the latter one doesn't exist).

Answer (score 6):

I know this is old but it might still be helpful for someone looking for the answer like I was.  If it doesn't work change the

```
<contains text="warnings"/>
```

to the text you see with your output.

```
<target name="javadoc">
<delete dir="${jDocDirectory}"/> 
<mkdir dir="${jDocDirectory}"/> 
<record name="javadocLog" action="start"/>
<javadoc (settings, blah blah) />
<record name="javadocLog" action="stop"/>
        <condition property="javadoc.warnings">
            <isfileselected file="javadocLog">
                <contains text="warnings"/>
             </isfileselected>
        </condition>
        <fail if="javadoc.warnings">Javadoc warnings!</fail>
</target>
```

edit:
If you have one warning this will not work, to fix for ALL warnings you must change this:

```
<contains text="warnings"/>
```

Comment: This seems interesting, though it doesn't work for me. I get a one-line blank text file as output from the record operation. It seems like <record> might not always be flushing the output to the file, so when you read it, you might get a really short file instead of a file containing the logs you were expecting. Back to the drawing board, I guess.

Comment: Your problem might be that you only have 1 warning and therefore the file contains "warning" instead of "warnings". We were having one warning that came up that could not be hidden/fixed (using a class that may be removed from the API). If you were to change the 

  <contains text="warning"/> 

That might help. This has been working for us since may, haven't had any issues yet.

Comment: I am using "warning", but the file is completely empty so it won't match. I'm now trying to figure out why <record> doesn't flush. The docs say it might only flush when a target is finished, so I tried using <antcall> on an empty target to force it, but that didn't seem to do it either.

Comment: Looks like I'm not the only one who has noticed this either (this one is back from 2002, amazing that it is still happening 10 years later!): http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/ant-user/200201.mbox/%3C06B707730144C5458B7D726295D19639283FE9@quadcal2.quadrus.com%3E

Comment: Great solution & still very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Ant 1.9.4 now has failonwarning="true"

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javadoc.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about a JavaDoc parameter, I would recommend using a tool like [checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) in your ant build for things like this. You can set it up to fail on Javadoc warnings.